# React router weird behaviour

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am having a problem with my code. The code below currently does not work. I have an appbar with 4 links leading to its corresponding js files. Each js files' content is only its label same as the links.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return ( 
      <div className="App">
        <ResponsiveAppBar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path="About" element={<About/>} />
          <Route path="Contact" element={<Contact/>} />
          <Route path="Register" element={<Register/>} />
          <Route path="Login" element={<Login/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**Nav.js**

```
function Nav() {
  return (

      <div className="App">
        <AppBar className='AppBar' style={{ background: '#8A252C', height: '100px' }}>
          <Toolbar style={{ height: '100%' }}>
            <img src='appbar.png' style={{height: '160px', width: '16%', marginBottom: '12px'}} alt='sidelogo'/>
            <div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
                <Link to={'/About'}>About Us</Link>
                <Link to={'/Contact'}>Contact Us</Link>
                <Link to={'/Register'}>Register</Link>
                <Link to={'/Login'}>Login</Link>
            </div>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>

  );
}

export default Nav;
```

**Pages/Home.js**

```
export default function Home (){
    return(
        <div>
          HOME
        </div> 
    );
}
```

**Pages/About.js**

```
export default function About (){
    return(
        <div>
          ABOUT US
        </div> 
    );
}
```

**Pages/Contact.js**

```
export default function Contact(){
    return(
        <div>
          CONTACT US
        </div> 
    );
}
```

**Pages/Register.js**

```
export default function Register(){
    return(
        <div>
          REGISTER
        </div> 
    );
}
```

**Pages/Login.js**

```
export default function Login(){
    return(
        <div>
          LOGIN
        </div> 
    );
}
```

Here's the weird part: I tried expermenting and I've got it to work. I added some lines of code for only the following files below:

**App.js V2**

```
function App() {
  return ( 
      <div className="App">
        <ResponsiveAppBar/>
        <Home/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path="About" element={<About/>} />
          <Route path="Contact" element={<Contact/>} />
          <Route path="Register" element={<Register/>} />
          <Route path="Login" element={<Login/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js V2**

```
export default function Home (){
    return(
        <div style={{ marginTop: '100px' }}>
          MAIN
          {/* <img src='bgtek.png' style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%',  }} alt='Landing'/> */}
        </div> 
    );
}
```

In App.js, I only added the tag . I wanted the home file to be the first displayed when I run my app.
In Home.js, I added a style to my div which is for my background image that I've commented.
The problem is the Home.js content will always display no matter which link I visit

If I remove these code changes, the routes will not work.

[image: Sample Image for when I visited About Us link. This applies to all links]

Can't seem to find any solutions.

Comment: Its always display, Like Navbar always display,
the content you replace when you redirect to other link is what inside Router tag,
if you want Home to be only render at first you need to add it to the router at some path and give router initial route